# Transitionend event not firing in Firefox 18 when a bootstrap modal closes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, transition

I have this problem on Firefox, on my website, click the "Post your event" button and then close the modal. As you can see the modal backdrop it's still there and prevent user interaction. This is the div

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade"></div>
```

I've read that firefox has some issues with transitions, but i've found mostly CSS problems/fixes, while this looks more like a js bug. Actually the problem is that transitionend event is never fired by FF.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Works for me in Firefox 18. Which version are you using?

Comment: Nevermind. I see. It appears to close but you can't click anything afterwards.